# Ensure content is positioned in viewport

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm trying to design a page which works on many different types of display sizes. Right now I have an important piece of content (a small rectangle showing current status, essentially) which is absolutely positioned inside a relatively positioned container.  This gives the desired behavior when the page is loaded in a device with a large screen: the content appears "above the fold" (no scrolling needed) at the intended position.

For devices with small screens (or, I suppose, browsers which aren't maximized) such that the box would appear off the first screen, I want the box to be shown at the bottom of the page until the user scrolls down far enough to return the box to its normal position, at which point it should resume that place.  (Yes, it should scroll off the top of the page if the user scrolls far enough down.)

I've seen this dynamic effect before, so it's definitely possible. (Something not entirely dissimilar is used at http://googleblog.blogspot.com/.) But how is it done? I don't think Javascript was used, though I could be wrong.

Obviously, a media query would not get the desired behavior, since that could give it a fixed position but not one which transitions in the desired fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this can't be done without javascript and a bit of jQuery wouldn't hurt either!

I would do it roughly like this.

```
<div id="box"></div>

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {

    if($('#box').position().top >= $(window).height()) {    // if box is outside window do this
        // position box inside window
        $('#box').css({ top: /* pixels go here */ });
    } else if(/* box is inside window */) {

    }

});
```